# untidy data- month day and year mixed observation under variable duration of swelling

Tags: r, data-cleaning

hi all
i have a dataset with a variable named duration of swelling observation in mixed format, some observation are in months , others in days and years. the unique values are 
`neck swelling` = c("1y", "2 Y", "1M", "-", "3.5Y", "8M", 
"1Y", "3M", "4M", "1.5Y", "6M", "2Y", "10Y", "8Y", "5Y", "5M", 
"3Y", "10M", "60D", "7M", "6Y", "20Y")
i want to clean these observations and to convert all to months.
how to do this

Answer (score 2):

**Quick and dirty solution:** replace the letters by numerical expressions for their lengths in months and multiply by the preceding numerical value:

```
s <- c("1y", "2 Y", "1M", "-", "3.5Y", "8M", "1Y", "3M", "4M", "1.5Y", "6M", "2Y", 
       "10Y", "8Y", "5Y", "5M", "3Y", "10M", "60D", "7M", "6Y", "20Y")

s.names <- s 
s <- sub("([[:digit:]]+([.][[:digit:]])*)[[:blank:]]*[yY]", "(\\1*12)", s) 
s <- sub("([[:digit:]]+([.][[:digit:]])*)[[:blank:]]*[dD]", "(\\1*(12/365))", s) 
s <- sub("([[:digit:]]+([.][[:digit:]])*)[[:blank:]]*[mM]", "(\\1)", s) 
names(s) <- s.names

sapply(s, function(s) tryCatch(eval(parse(text=s)), error = function(e) NA_real_))
```

> ```
>         1y        2 Y         1M          -       3.5Y         8M         1Y         3M 
>  12.000000  24.000000   1.000000         NA  42.000000   8.000000  12.000000   3.000000 
>         4M       1.5Y         6M         2Y        10Y         8Y         5Y         5M 
>   4.000000  18.000000   6.000000  24.000000 120.000000  96.000000  60.000000   5.000000 
>         3Y        10M        60D         7M         6Y        20Y 
>  36.000000  10.000000   1.972603   7.000000  72.000000 240.000000
> ```

The output is a named vector: the names are the original strings and its values are their numerical equivalents.  Unrecognizable strings are converted to `NA` -- you can readily change that by modifying the output of the error function handler on the last line.

---

In a large data frame, turn the strings into factors; convert the factor labels; and join the converted values to the frame.  This will be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As to the math, what I would do is choose your smallest interval (day) and convert everything to that, adding uniform noise to the data that is on longer intervals.

First, you'd have to make sure the data are coded consistently (e.g. issues with spaces, capital letters, etc.)  How to do that is off topic here, but shouldn't be too hard.

Then, something like this pseudocode

```
If swelling = "1Y" then swellday = 365 + runif(1, 0, 365)
If swelling = "1M" then swellday = 30 + runif(1, 0, 30)
```

and so on.

If you have additional knowledge about what the 1M and 1Y (and so on) mean, then you can incorporate that.

Comment: Adding the noise appears guaranteed to introduce a bias into the data.  The pseudocode would be cumbersome to create: you need a line for every possible value of the input.  There are better ways.